# LabVIEW: Elapsed time inside case structure does not work on second time

Tags: labview

I need to make a next programm: there is a switch and a LED. When you turn on the switch LED turns on with given seconds delay (if you turn the switch off during this delay - LED won't turn on), then when you turn the switch of - LED turns off with second given delay (if you turn the switch on during this delay - LED won't turn off). I have created the code on the picture, but it works correctly only on the first time I turn the switch on and off, then it starts to turn on and off without or with a very low delay

I have tried to set up auto reset after reaching the time target of Elapsed time but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: There is no code attached (although you mention it). Please edit your post, and add code snippet rather than simple screenshot. Check this link https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000x2PkCAI to see how to create code snippet.